# Thread 8: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, sigabrt

I am trying to parse my api response in Swift.
But, I am getting following error

> Thread 8: signal SIGABRT

My json modal class is

```
struct storyDataClass : Codable {
    var storyDictionary :  storyDictionary?
}

struct storyDictionary: Codable {
    var nameString : String?
    var lineString : String?
    var image : String?
}
```

and API call is

```
    dataViewModelClass.getData(completionHandler: {data, error -> Void in
        if (data != nil) {
            
            print(data?.count)
            
            if let retriveData = data {
                
                for (index,value) in retriveData.enumerated() {
                    print(index)
                  //  print(value)
                    
                    var dataJson = storyDataClass.init(storyDictionary: value as! storyDictionary)
                    
                    print(dataJson.storyDictionary?.lineString)

                }
            }
            
        } else {
            print("api.getData failed")
            print(error as! NSError)
        }
    })
```

In the response, value has multiple dictionaries under Story key.

```
{
    "name" = "name";
    line = "some name";
    "image" = "https://";
   }
{
    "name" = "name";
    line = "some name";
    "image" = "https://";
   }
```

And the API call back method

```
class DataViewViewModel {
    
    typealias DataCompletion = (String) -> Void

    func getData(completionHandler: ((Array<Any>?, Error?) -> Void)!) -> Void {
        
        let url = URL(string: mainDataURL)
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil {
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
                return completionHandler(nil, error)
            } else {
                do {
                    let parsedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!) as! [String:Any]
                    let itemsArray = parsedData["items"] as! Array<Any>
                    print(itemsArray)
                   return completionHandler(itemsArray, nil)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            }.resume()

    }
    
}
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the crash? Do you have an error in console ? ` value as! storyDictionary` seems quite strange (and is asking for a crash since there is a forceunwrap).

Comment: Can you post how the "dataViewModelClass.getData" method looks like?

Comment: Use JSONDecoder to decode your json data. You can go through https://medium.com/@nictheawesome/using-codable-with-nested-json-is-both-easy-and-fun-19375246c9ff

Comment: Updated query with screenshot of error.

Comment: So `retriveData` is a `Array<Any>`. So `value` is a `Any`. Who told you it's a `storyDictionary`, you didn't transform it into a `storyDictionary` object yet. Learn about Codable properly, you are mixing JSONSerialization & Codable (and it's not good).